# In git how to merge the Feature branch into Main branch and then Resynchronize

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, synchronize

We have a feature branch "`feature`" created from the main branch "`main`".

We did changes in "`feature`" and then merged into "`main`"

In the meantime others also merged their changes in "`main`". If we want these changes in "`main`" to also come back to "`feature`" what is the best way - i.e. we want to resynchronize "`feature`" with "`main`"

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:
Check out the main branch again:

```
git checkout main
```

Pull the latest changes:

```
git pull
```

Check out feature branch again and merge main into feature branch:

```
git checkout feature
git merge main
```

You can do this quicker, but this is the - to me - most intuitive way.